# NVIDIA Driver required for steamVR

Tags: nvidia, steam

So, I want to get steamVR for ubuntu and I want to know if I need the NVIDIA GPU Driver to operate SteamVR?

Answer (score 0):

It's been [reported](https://www.gamingonlinux.com/articles/steamvr-for-linux-is-now-officially-in-beta.9156) that on NVIDIA cars, you need to have the 375.27.10 "Developer Beta Driver", and for Ubuntu there's a PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/~mamarley/+archive/ubuntu/nvidia-dev/+packages) that has packages for Artful, Zesty, Xenial, and Trusty. You can add this untrusted PPA with the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mamarley/nvidia-dev
sudo apt-get update
```

and install with

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-graphics-drivers-381
```

**NOTE:** This answer is based on research as I do not have the gear necessary for testing.

Sources:

https://www.gamingonlinux.com/articles/steamvr-for-linux-is-now-officially-in-beta.9156

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/819624/can-you-provide-a-repository-for-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu/?offset=6